# Magento how to add a product with dynamic pricing capability

Tags: magento-1.9

I have to display a product on magento 1.9 which has 5 distinct attributes that determine price, namely:

```
   1, Size (9,14,18)
   2, Metal (Gold, Silver)
   3, Gender (Women, Men)
   4, Stone (Diamond, Swarovsky)
```

I have made the attribute(configurable) for each and added to attribute set. Each one of these would alter the price based on drop down selection.

How can i make it work making it dynamic price such as the price will change dynamically based on each drop down selection. for example:

> Blockquote

```
1, Size->Metal->Gender->Stone
2, 9->Gold->Set->Diamond = $5000
3, 9->Gold->Set->Swarovsky = $3000
4, 9->Silver->Women->Diamond = $4500
```

> `Blockquote`

So we have multiple options here for price selection. Is this something magento can handle or only option is to use a third-part extension.

Do you know any free third-party extension for this or any way it can be coded to upload xml,csv files of these combination allowing the price to change every time the user selects different option.

Thanks.

Comment: FYI, I'm fairly certain silver isn't a gender (but hey, what do I know?)

Comment: Oh yea...added by mistake. :)